# CSS Flex - Adjustment - Equal rows

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a little problem fine=tuning my CSS menu.
In a small range of screen size, the left side is pushed in 2 rows, but the right side remains in 1 row. How can I enforce that both sides have the same row count? So if not enough space is on the one side, the other side will also be wrapped in a second row, so it is equally distributed?

So it is always like this:

```
    Link1 Link2 Link3   LOGO  Link5 Link6 Link7
            LongLink4         Link8

    Link1 Link2 Link3   LOGO  Link6 Link7 Link8
          Link4 Link5         Link9 Link10
```

AND NOT

```
    Link1 Link2 Link3  Link4  LOGO  Link6 Link7 Link8 Link9 Link10
                   LongLink5
```

```html
navbar>.container, .navbar>.container-fluid, .navbar>.container-lg, .navbar>.container-md, .navbar>.container-sm, .navbar>.container-xl, .navbar>.container-xxl {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: inherit;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.container, .container-fluid, .container-lg, .container-md, .container-sm, .container-xl, .container-xxl {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: var(--gutter-x, 0.5em);
    padding-left: var(--gutter-x, 0.5em);
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
.container-fluid {
    padding-left: 32px;
    padding-right: 32px;
}
section, .container, .container-fluid {
    position: relative;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the right side a max-width and use flex-wrap could help

Comment: problem was  that the width was set to 100% on both sides, by removing this, it works. so the guess with max-width helped ;)